# Make a Docker application write to stdout

Tags: logging, cluster, docker, coreos

I'm deploying a 3rd-party application in compliance with the [12 factor advisory](http://12factor.net/), and one of the points tell that application logs should be printed to stdout/stderr: then clustering software can collect it.

However, the application can only write to files or syslog. How do I print these logs instead?

Comment: They are already going to syslog. You can just pick them up from there!

Comment: @MichaelHampton, seems fine, but Docker runs a single process that can write to stdout, and this sounds like combining two of them?

Comment: You can have a daemon process use syslog and have a front process which prints?

Answer (score 161, accepted):

An amazing recipe is given in the [nginx Dockerfile](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/8921999083def7ba43a06fabd5f80e4406651353/mainline/jessie/Dockerfile#L21-L23):

```
# forward request and error logs to docker log collector
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log \
    && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

Simply, the app can continue writing to it as a file, but as a result the lines will go to `stdout` & `stderr`!

Comment: This. Is. Just. Brilliant. 
And versatile.

Comment: The one thing that's a problem with this is when the thing you're running insists on forking itself to the background as a non-root process. I'm having this with `squid3`, and it then has trouble with permissions on `/dev/stdout`.

Comment: This doesn't always work - for example if the application attempts to seek the file, this method will generally not work.

Comment: Link is down...

Comment: Everything is a file for the win.

Comment: softlink isn't required with the latest Nginx. You can simply redirect to stdout and stderr.

Comment: Please note that this works for most cases however if your application doing the logging is not running as PID 1, then the logs will not redirect to the stdout that Docker reads from.

Comment: I have multiple access.log and error.log(access log per server block) how would this even work??

Comment: Actually I'm struggling with MySQL to get the logs to the stdout of the container, and even after having linked the log files to `/dev/stdout` in the `Dockerfile` or in the entrypoint script, and even with mysqld running as PID 1, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: This may not be optimal if you want Fail2Ban to look at your Nginx logs.  I think you could have Fail2Ban look at the Docker Nginx container log `/var/lib/docker/containers/<container ID>/<container ID>-json.log` (which is where the STDOUT and STDERR data will be directed to), but that is kind of a pain.

Answer (score 49):

For a background process in a docker container, e.g. connecting with exec to /bin/bash I was able to use.

```
echo "test log1" >> /proc/1/fd/1
```

This sends the output to the stdout of pid 1, which is the one docker pick's up and logs.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The logs should be sent to stdout for PID1 and if your application is running under another PID, it won't be seen by `docker logs` or `kubectl logs`. I have a container that schedules task through crontab which isn't running as PID1.

Comment: @leeman24 this is not correct: any process forked from PID1 will inherit all open FDs including `stdout` and `stderr`, i.e. the `stdout` of forked processes will be collected by `docker logs` as well. Only if a forked process closes or changes its `stdout` to something else it won't be available in `docker logs` anymore. _Then_ you can use `/proc/1/fd/1` to "reconnect" the output to `docker logs`.

Comment: Simplest, easiest, reliable.

Answer (score 19):

In another question, [Kill child process when the parent exits](https://serverfault.com/questions/599192/kill-child-process-when-the-parent-exits), I got the response that helped to sort this out.

This way, we configure the application so it logs to a file, and continuously `tail -f` it. 
Luckily, `tail` can accept `--pid PID`: it will exit when the specified process exits. We put `$$` there: PID of the current shell.

As a final step, the launched application is `exec`'ed, which means that the current shell is completely replaced with that application.

Runner script, `run.sh`, will look like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
set -eu

rm -rf /var/log/my-application.log
tail --pid $$ -F /var/log/my-application.log &

exec /path/to/my-application --logfile /var/log/my-application.log
```

NOTE: by using `tail -F` we list filenames, and it will read them even if they appear later!

Finally, the minimalistic Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
ADD run.sh /root/run.sh
CMD ['/root/run.sh']
```

---

Note: to workaroung some extremely strange `tail -f` behavior (which says "has been replaced with a remote file. giving up on this name") i tried another approach: all known log files are created & truncated on start up: this way I ensure they exist, and only then -- tail them:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
set -eu

LOGS=/var/log/myapp/

( umask 0 && truncate -s0 $LOGS/http.{access,error}.log )
tail --pid $$ -n0 -F $LOGS/* &

exec /usr/sbin/apache2 -DFOREGROUND
```

Comment: Especially for Apache server I'm using Piped logs (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html#piped) and looks like it works.

Comment: The solves similar issues with alpine and seems to work fine on BusyBox `tail` without the --pid option.

Comment: the workaround worked for me. extreme useful, thank you.

Comment: While this works pretty great with Docker, it doesn't with Kubernetes! I don't know why but the `tail` process is missing in the pod's container...

Answer (score 7):

for nginx you can have `nginx.conf` pointing to `/dev/stderr` and `/dev/stdout` like this

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  4;
error_log  /dev/stderr;
http {
    access_log  /dev/stdout  main;
...
```

and your `Dockerfile` entry should be

```
/usr/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

Comment: Does not work when master process is not running as `root`

Answer (score 3):

In my case making a symbolic link to stdout didn't work so instead I run the following command

```
ln -sf /proc/self/fd/1 /var/log/main.log
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just had to solve this problem with apache2, and wrestled with using CustomLog to try redirecting to `/proc/1/fd/1` but couldn't get that working. In my implementation, apache was not running as `pid 1`, so [kolypto's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/634296/531769) didn't work as is. [Pieter's approach](https://serverfault.com/a/932888/531769) seemed compelling, so I merged the two and the result works wonderfully:

```
# Redirect apache log output to docker log collector
RUN ln -sf /proc/1/fd/1 /var/log/apache2/access.log \
    && ln -sf /proc/1/fd/2 /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Technically this keeps the apache `access.log` and `error.log` going to `stdout` and `stderr` as far as the docker log collector is concerned, but it'd be great if there were a way to separate the two *outside* the container, like a switch for `docker logs` that would show only one or the other...