# Kill child process when the parent exits

Tags: bash, scripting, process

I'm preparing a script for Docker, which allows only one top-level process, which should receive the signals so we can stop it.

Therefore, I'm having a script like this: one application writes to syslog (bash script in this sample), and the other one just prints it.

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
set -eu

tail -f /var/log/syslog &

exec bash -c 'while true ; do logger aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa ; sleep 1 ; done'
```

Almost solved: when the top-level process `bash` gets SIGTERM -- it exists, but `tail -f` continues to run.

How do I instruct `tail -f` to exit when the parent process exits? E.g. it should also get the signal.

Note: Can't use bash traps since `exec` on the last line replaces the process completely.

Comment: Isn't this what things like `supervisord` are supposed to handle?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, you're right, but in this case I really need to print something out. Supervisor is not good at printing :)

Comment: I read your other question too. You really should describe what's actually going on, and name the applications you're working with.

Comment: Could you try tail -f --pid="$$" filename?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, okay, let's say that's Apache. It can only log to files or syslog, and not to stdout. I need to have logging to stdout :)

Comment: I got that part already. But it isn't Apache. What is it really?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, supervisor running multiple processes: apache, redis,  cron (bundled them to simplify the setup). In other cases this can be any app which only can write to logfiles. stdout logs is a requirement for 12-factor apps to run in a cloud, namely, CoreOS

Comment: @kupson hahaha oh my gosh, never thought `tail` can do that! Amazing! Post as an answer, I'll accept it :)

Comment: Apache can log to anything you want, including an external command. So using it as an example makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, ErrorLog `|cat` does not output anything since when Apache launches this external command - it discards its output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are lucky^Wusing tail command from GNU coreutils you can use `--pid=<number>` option. The capital `-F` option would make you safe against log rotation.

```
tail --pid="$$" -F /var/log/syslog &
```

More info: http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tail-invocation.html