# How to tell my apache server running in a docker container to write logs to stdout

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I have been trying to point my logs to /proc/1/fd/1 but it is saying cannot acces the directory and if i use /proc/self/fd/1 nothing is writing to my stdout

Answer (score 0):

See the accepted answer of
[Make a Docker application write to stdout](https://serverfault.com/questions/599103/make-a-docker-application-write-to-stdout)

You would rather soft link to the actual log location to `/dev/{stdout,stderr}`