# Lighttpd alpine container logging

Tags: docker, lighttpd, alpine

The context is that I want to serve a static website inside a docker container so I can have some dedicated metrics, and I want the logs to use stdout/stderr.

To do that I thought of using Lighttpd with an Alpine image.

I found a tip [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/599103/make-a-docker-application-write-to-stdout) where we create a link to stdout, but after creating the link the permissions change and lighttpd stops writing to access.log.

I've tried changing `server.username` on lighttpd.conf to "root" but it refuses to do so saying '
*(server.c.1330) I will not set uid to 0*.

I've tried changing the access.log permissions after the link creation with no success.

Is there a way to configure lighttpd to use stdout/stderr?

**My currently config:**

```
var.basedir  = "/var/www/localhost"
var.logdir   = "/var/log/lighttpd"
var.statedir = "/var/lib/lighttpd"

server.modules   = ( "mod_access",
                     "mod_setenv",
                     "mod_rewrite",
                     "mod_redirect",
                     "mod_status",
                     "mod_simple_vhost",
                     "mod_evhost",
                     "mod_alias",
                     "mod_userdir",
                     "mod_secdownload",
                     "mod_fastcgi",
                     "mod_proxy",
                     "mod_cgi",
                     "mod_ssi",
                     "mod_compress",
                     "mod_usertrack",
                     "mod_expire",
                     "mod_rrdtool",
                     "mod_accesslog" )

include "mime-types.conf"

server.errorlog   = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
server.pid-file      = "/var/run/lighttpd.pid"

server.username             = "lighttpd"
server.groupname            = "wheel"

server.document-root = var.basedir + "/htdocs"

static-file.exclude-extensions = (".php", ".pl", ".cgi", ".fcgi")

url.access-deny = ("~", ".inc")

accesslog.filename = "/var/log/lighttpd/access.log"
index-file.names            = ( "index.php", "index.html", "index.lighttpd.html" )
```

**My currently Dockerfile:**

```
FROM alpine:3.12

RUN adduser -S lighttpd -G wheel
RUN apk update --no-cache
RUN apk add  --update --no-cache \
    lighttpd=1.4.55-r1

COPY ./static /var/www/localhost/htdocs/
COPY lighttpd/* /etc/lighttpd/

RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/lighttpd/access.log \
   && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/lighttpd/error.log

EXPOSE 80 443

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/lighttpd", "-D", "-f", "/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you comment out `server.errorlog`, then lighttpd will log to stderr.

If `accesslog.filename = "/dev/stdout"` does not work, then have you tried setting `accesslog.filename = "/proc/self/fd/1"` ?

Comment: I am running into the same problem. I've tried both `/dev/stdout` and `/proc/self/fd/1` and both do not work.